# Drawing arcs in SVG without using translate function

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to move an arc on top of svg without using translate/transform function? I cannot use this function because, I am using a library which do not accepts translate function while exporting these svg into images.

sample code is here:
    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    var pi = Math.PI;

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(50)
.outerRadius(70)
.startAngle(45 * (pi/180))
.endAngle(3)

vis.attr("width", "400").attr("height", "400")
.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("transform", "translate(100,200)");
```

Comment: SVG uses its coordinates space to define positions, so in pure SVG it is easy to do by just defining coordinates of the path (that is arc). I never worked with D3 though so unsure how they handle it;/

Comment: `d3.svg.arc()` (v3) or `d3.arc()` (v4/5) doesn't provide methods to set a center coordinate, the arcs are placed with a translate. This means that you can't place the arc anywhere except centered at 0,0 without a translate.